# What is the maximal size of a subset of consecutive integers such that they are all coprime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose that $a$,$b$, and $n$ are positive integers such that $a = b - n$. In terms of $n$, what is the largest number of integers $z_1,z_2,z_3,\cdots, z_m$ all between $a$ and $b$ such that all $z$ are coprime to each other?

I feel like this is something I should be able to find online somewhere, but I couldn't find it. I'm not looking for a proof so much as just looking for the current proven metric. I know it cannot be more than roughly $\frac n2$.

Comment: Um.... 3.  z_1 and z_2 will always be relatively prime.  z_1, z_2, z_3 will be relatively prime if and only if z_1 and z_3 are both odd.  z_1, z_2, z_3 and z_4 will never be relatively prime because two will be even.

Comment: Okay, In rereading you didn't mean consecutive.  You meant strictly between a and b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't quite clear. My understanding is that you are asking: Given an integer n, which is the maximum number of co-prime numbers in an interval [a, b] with b - a = n?

Among your numbers, at most one may be divisible by 2. At most one may be divisible by 3, by 5 and so on. Assume you found m numbers of which no two have a common prime factor up to p, and q is the next prime number after p. Let P = product of all primes up to p. If m ≤ 2q - 1 then there is a remainder r such that at most one number is equal to r (modulo q). By adding the right multiple of P, you can find numbers such that no two are divisible by the same prime p, and no two are divisible by q. We can repeat this, getting bigger numbers but with the same property. Eventually q > n, and then no two numbers can be divisible by q or any bigger prime, and at that point we have found m co-prime numbers.

So you can try to find $m_2$ integers of which no two are even, then $m_3$ integers of which no two are divisible by 3 and so on. Once $m_p ≤ 2q - 1$ you know the answer is m. With n = 20 you can find 10 numbers: 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31. For large n, say n = 1000, if you took any interval [a, b] of 1001 numbers, you would remove almost half the numbers because they are even, almost one third of the remainder because they are divisible by 3, almost one fifth because they are divisible by 5, then almost one seventh, so more than 3/4s of the numbers would be gone. Finding a maximum set will be very, very hard once n gets a bit larger.

Comment: I was think of 17 consecutive  in the shower.  I figured there could be 1 even and 9 odds.  So thats 10.  From 9 odd 6 are divisible by 3. Select the even, an odd divisible by 3 and 6 of the remaining odds.  Then I realized there need not be more than one multiple of 5 in the group nor even as many as 1.  I think when you get to $p_i*p_{i+1}\approx n $ you don't have to consider higher.

Comment: Well any three consecutive numbers beginning or ending with an odd number are coprime. If k is odd then k,k+2,k+4 are co prime and whichever k+1 or k+3 that is not divisible by 3 is also coprime.  But the issue isn't the smallest you can guaramtee but the must you can possibly have.

Comment: I was getting at you could have as many as 7.

Comment: Example 7,8,9,11,13,17,19,23 are between 6 and 24.  But I don't think you can get more than 8 in a 16 number range.

Comment: It should be easy to always get roughly or slightly more  than $[\prod (p_i -1)/p_i p]+k$ for the k primes that are less than n. I'm not sure how to fine tune it or to specify the specifics based on n and b.

Comment: The thing is, you can include 1 even, and 1 odd divisible by three.  And then if one of the odds divide by 3 that was remove is divisible by 5 you don't have to remove it so the number you can leave in goes up.  If the prime whose multiples you are removing becomes a sinificant proportion of those left it can really skew your numbers upward.  For example, with n =7 after removing evens and multiples of 3, I didn't need to remove any multiples of 5 or 7 or any other numbers at all.

Comment: @fleablood Interestingly, the contribution from being able to retain one even number, one multiple of three, etc. turns out to be negligible in a sense that can be made precise.  I'll post an answer that summarizes the relevant literature.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is closely related to the seminal work of Hensley and Richards on admissible $k$-tuples.  Let $r(n)$ be the maximum cardinality indicated in the question.  Clearly we have the lower bound $r(n) \ge \pi(n)$ by taking $a=1, b=n+1$ and choosing all primes up to $n$.  We could also include $1$ itself and $n+1$ if it happens to be prime, but this only contributes a bounded amount to the maximum.  Consequently the research on this question has been directed towards understanding the nature of $r(n) - \pi(n)$.

This was first considered by Erdős and Selfridge in their 1971 paper "Complete prime subsets of consecutive integers", where they showed ([PDF link](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1971-03.pdf)) that for infinitely many values of $n$, $$r(n) - \pi(n) > (\log 2 - \tfrac12 - o(1)) \frac{n}{(\log n)^2}.$$

As observed by fleablood in the comments, a valid set is allowed to contain one even number, one multiple of $3$, one multiple of $5$, etc.  At the time of the previous paper, it appears that Erdős may have believed that these contributions are essential to the above lower bound.

However, this was disproven by Hensley and Richards in their famous 1974 paper "Primes in intervals" ([PDF link](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa25/aa2548.pdf)).  There, they considered the maximum cardinality of a subset of integers in $[a,a+n]$ which contains **no** even numbers, **no** multiples of $3$, and so on up to $n$.  Calling this $\rho(n)$, they showed that:

$$\rho(n) - \pi(n) > (\log 2 - o(1)) \frac{n}{(\log n)^2}.$$

Since clearly $\rho(n) \le r(n)$, this also improves the bound of Erdős and Selfridge.  This surely attracted Erdős's attention and soon afterwards he co-authored "Density Functions for Prime and Relatively Prime Numbers" with Hensley ([PDF link](http://renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1977-09.pdf)).  There they showed that in fact

$$r(n) - \rho(n) = o(\frac{n}{(\log n)^2}),$$

so that the difference between "at most one multiple of $p$" and "no multiples of $p$" is surprisingly small compared to $\rho(n) - \pi(n)$ itself.

As of 1985, the question of whether $r(n)-\pi(n)$ is truly $\Theta(n/(\log n)^2)$ or something even larger was still open, as Erdős listed it as one of his favorite open problems in http://www.math-inst.hu/~p_erdos/1985-17.pdf.

Some computational data: [OEIS A062575](https://oeis.org/A062575) contains a table of the values of $r(n)$ for the first $76$ values of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your post says *consecutive* integers. If that is the case, $n=2$, for a total of 3 elements of the set.

Proof:

Let $a=11$. Then count until we find a number that is not coprime to any others. We have to stop at $b=14$, because $12$ and $14$ are both divisible by 2. So our set has 3 members, namely $\{11, 12, 13\}$.

Even if we start with super small positive integers, for example $a=3$, we can't have more than $\{3, 4, 5\}$ because the next integer, $6$, is divisible by the first integer, $3$.

Comment: The title and the Q do not match. So you can answer whichever you like :)

Comment: I think the OP might have been thinking "what is the maximal size of a subset of *a set of* consecutive numbers".  Or what is the maximal size of a set of numbers taken from a sequence of n consecutive numbers.  Consecutive seems to refer to the superset from which the subset is taken.  (We really should use the term "superset" more often, shouldn't we?)

Comment: I honestly think most people would think "a subset of consecutive integers" or "a X of consecutive integers" would mean the subset consists of consecutive integers.  It could be interpreted the way you intended but I think that is an *incorrect* way and that you are the one in error for so stating.  The phrase "consecutive integers" is not the same as "a set of consecutive integers" so "a subset of consecutive integers" is not the same as "a subset of a set of consecutive integers".  We could avoid this by saying "a subset *from* consecutive integers".

Comment: A common idiom in number theory would be "pairwise relatively prime integers in a short interval".  The relevant quantity here is the *length* of the interval, since every (finite) subset of integers is literally a subset of a set of consecutive integers.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't entirely an answer, but I wrote some Haskell code meant to be the largest subset between a particular $a$ and $b$. It seems to give much larger values than I was expecting. If anyone has any suggestions please feel free to let me know. Once again, this is just as a tool to help in this problem. It seems very very hard to prove in general.

**The following is Haskell source code. DO NOT apply math jax. It will mess it up.**

---

```
    subsets []  = [[]]
    subsets (x:xs) = subsets xs ++ map (x:) (subsets xs)

    divides a b = (mod a b == 0)

    coprime a b = ((gcd a b) == 1)

    mutually_coprime []  = True
    mutually_coprime (x:xs) | (coprime_list x xs) = mutually_coprime xs
                            | otherwise = False

    coprime_list _ [] = True
    coprime_list a (x:xs) | (coprime a x) = coprime_list a xs
                          | otherwise = False

    coprime_subsets a b = coprime_subsets_helper (subsets [a..b])

    coprime_subsets_helper [] = []
    coprime_subsets_helper (x:xs) | ((mutually_coprime x) && ((list_length x) > 2)) = [x] ++ (coprime_subsets_helper xs)
                                  | otherwise = coprime_subsets_helper xs

    coprime_subset_length a b = max_element (map list_length (coprime_subsets a b))

    list_length [] = 0
    list_length (x:xs) = 1 + list_length xs

    max_element a = max_element_helper a 0

    max_element_helper [] a = a
    max_element_helper (x:xs) a | (x > a) = max_element_helper xs x
                                | otherwise = max_element_helper xs a
```

Comment: Thanks for this contribution! It would be great if you could post some of the results you've computed as well :).

Comment: If you only care about the maximum over all $a$ (as opposed to a specific interval $[a,b]$), then probably you should exploit the fact that this is equivalent (via Chinese Remainder Theorem) to finding a maximal subset $S$ of $1,\ldots,n$ with the property that for each prime $p \le n$ the histogram of $S$ modulo $p$ contains at least one bucket with a frequency $\le 1$.  I'm guessing that should be more efficient than considering all subsets of $[a,b]$ and iterating over multiple values of $a$ on top of that.

Comment: In computer language parlance, the criterion "the histogram ... frequency $\le 1$", means the same as: initialize an integer array of length $p$ to `0` and increment the value at index `s%p` for each element `s` of $S$, then check whether the resulting array contains a `0` or `1`.  Hope that helps understand what I mean.

Comment: Some maximum values have been computed here: https://oeis.org/A062575.  There are also minimum (well, minimax) values here: https://oeis.org/A062571.